# Axios can not GET json data from another localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, axios

I'm creating an application, the front end in React JC and I have a basic REST api made with Node JS. When I try fetch data from localhost:3001/user/:id for example on postman - everything works 100%.

But when I try to fetch it on my front end in React (the react app is hosted on localhost:3000/), it delivers the following error:

> "Failed to load localhost:3001/user/5b21a5d7588b40be612798d4: Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https."

The relevant code where I'm trying to fetch the data on my front end (with Axios is here):

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get("localhost:3001/user/5b21a5d7588b40be612798d4").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })

  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a browser plugin that allows cross origin resource sharing. You'll need to turn it on, and then it should work.

Keep in mind, a lot of sites disable their services when you have it on for security reasons, like YouTube. So only keep it on while working on your project.

Comment: This did the trick! will also probably make me more productive if Youtube is disabled ;)

Comment: That's a feature :)

Answer (score 10):

You have to specify the protocol at the begining of the URL

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/user/5b21a5d7588b40be612798d4").then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }
```

Comment: that's not the source of the issue. the real reason is CORS policy. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US helped me.

Comment: Tried the extension, same result for me

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the network tab and hovering over the request to see the error usually gives you a better indication of what the error is than in the log.

As well as CORS issues, another problem that I have experienced before is the browsers rejecting the request when the localhost server is using a self-signed certificate. The browsers do not trust them and will not let the request through, while Postman will. You can either add an exception for the certificate (not recommended) or get a signed certificate from somewhere like https://letsencrypt.org/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS in your node project . Their is a npm package named cors you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9) solved my problem in no time.

> The quickest fix you can make is to install the [moesif CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en-US) . Once installed, click it in your browser to activate the extension. Make sure the icon’s label goes from “off” to “on“

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32706777)

Comment: The extension didn't help for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked, when I put my network IP address instead of localhost
Just put the IP address, like this

```
http://190.168.0.100:3000/your_route
```